# Writing useful generic test class

Tags: java, unit-testing, generics

I have the following interface:

```
public interface Combiner<U, W> {
  U combine(W[] args);
}
```

I also have an Assembler class which has a handle to a Combiner instance and uses it to return a result of generic type U, after passing in an array of type W, as such:

```
U result = myCombiner.combine(results);
```

I'm trying to write a small unit test to test the Assembler. The challenge is how to write a useful Combiner test instance. All I can think of doing is to take the first element of the array and cast it to a U.

```
public class MyCombiner<U, W> implements Combiner<U, W> {
    @Override
    public U combine(W[] args) {
        U u = (U) args[0];
        return u;
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is sum up all of the elements of W[] and add to U, but this assumes that the types are Numbers. I know I can use `U extends Number`, and `W extends Number` in MyCombiner, but then it won't work if the U and W are String types. How can I write this generic class in a way that is more useful to testing my Assembler? I want to avoid Mock objects if possible. Plus I'm not sure if the problem will still exist with Mocks.

Comment: Using mocks the problem automatically disappears since you'd only test the Asembler, and the only responsibilty of the asembler is to call the combiner. What happens inside the combiner is out of the scope of the Asembler test.

Comment: Was able to create a usable test stub for the Combiner by extending the U and W types from Number. That said, I agree a mock would be a more flexible approach.